# Is php 7 now rolling out as the default php version?

Tags: 16.04, php7

I just saw php 7 packages in my apt-get upgrade, so I'm wondering...

Answer (score 2):

Yes, in Ubuntu 16.04 PHP 7 is the default PHP version